# unable to convert from fahrenheit f to centigrade c

Tags: java

Trying to convert it using 2 methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class myProgram {
    public double convertTemp(double tempF) {
        return 5/9*(tempF-32);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter fahrenhiet tempreature");
        double tempF= sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("the tempreature of fahrenheit in celsius is",convertTemp(tempF));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Int division:** In Java, when you divide 2 ints, the result is always an int.

Therefore, you need to divide doubles, or start the operation with a double.

```
public static double convertTemp(double tempF) { // Note that this must be static to be called from a static context
    return (tempF - 32) * 5/9;
}
```

**Printf:** If you are gonna use `printf`, you must remember adding the %f on the string to be substituted

```
System.out.printf("the tempreature of fahrenheit in celsius is %f", convertTemp(tempF));
```

Answer (score 1):

`5/9` is equal to zero in Java, try with `5.0/9`

Answer (score 0):

The code as submitted won't compile because you are calling convertTemp() (an instance method) from a static context.

That means that the method is part of the MyProgram class but you are not creating an instance of MyProgram

If you don't want to create an instance, make your convertTemp method static.

`public static double convertTemp`

or create an instance of MyProgram.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myProgram myp = new myProgram();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tempF= sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("the tempreature of fahrenheit in celsius is",myp.convertTemp(tempF));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling non-static method from static method. Even though class has both methods, you need to create object and than call the method using dot operator. Also if you want to return double value you need to use 5.0 and not 5.